# Peugeot 206, engine oil level fine, but the 6 segments flash indicates fault

Tags: engine, oil, peugeot, instrument

The peugeot 206 has the oil level gauge in picture:

[image]

specifically in that state means "fault". Today I've noticed my oil engine gauge  light is in that state. I've checked the oil level, it seems fine (halfway between min and max, I mean it's not overfilled).

So what could the cause be? Shall I get it to the mechanic?